# How I update my custom module without uninstall and reinstall it?

Tags: entities

I need to add a column in my custom field type. So I written code for adding column in field_schema function and in functions that display the field. Now, I need to update the module without uninstall and reinstall it. There is a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) exists for exactly that reason. For example:

```
function MYMODULE_update_7100(&$sandbox) {
  // Perform your update here
}
```

It's worth remembering update hooks should b found in your module's.install file.